# How to generate dynamic array of objects in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I want to pass the array of string `names` in to the function and be able to generate the array of objects based on that.

Say I am passing `{ 'id', 'title' }` and as an output I am getting

```
[
    {
      id: '1',
      title: 'o1'
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      title: 'o2'
    },
]
```

I am kind of stucked as not sure how would you take the array of stirngs and convert its elements in to an object

```
export function getItems(names) {

  const a: any[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      // need to produce 5 objects here like:
      // {
      //  id: '1',
      //  title: 'o1'
      // }
      a.push(object);
  }

  return a;
}
```

thoughts?

Comment: How are you providing the values for these keys? I mean, name='o1', name='02' etc. Are they random>

Comment: yup. You need to tell us how the values will be assigned to the properties? Also an array would be ['id', 'title'] not {'id', 'title'}.

Comment: This should be statement inside the loop a.push({id: `${i+1}`, title: `o${i+1}`});

Comment: @ivp the values are gonna be assigned in the loop from `1` to `5`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not provided much information, but this should work for you.

```
function getItems(names) {
  const a: any[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    a.push(names.reduce((acc, val) => {
      acc[val] = val + i
      return acc
    }, {}));
  }
  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> This should do it

```js
function manufactureArray(props, num) {
  var arr = [];
  var obj;

  // Loop for the number of objects you want to push to the array
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    obj = {};

    // Create the properties within a new object, and push it into the array
    for (var j = 0; j < props.length; j++) {

      // Using square bracket creates a property,
      // so this line will become: obj["id"] = "0 0" and so on
      obj[props[j]] = i + " " + j;
    }

    arr.push(obj);
  }

  return arr;
}

var num = prompt("Enter array length");

var arr = manufactureArray(['id', 'title'], num);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you @Abhijit

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
type Obj = {[key: number]: number}
function getItems(names: number[]) {

  const arr: Obj[] = []; // your array is an array of Obj Type

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // obj also is of type Obj
    const obj = names.reduce((acc, val) => {
      acc[val] = val + i
      return acc;
    }, {} as Obj)
    // here you can push obj in your array
    arr.push(obj);
  }
  return arr;
}
```